# Fixing error caused by importing CtCILibrary

Tags: java

I am trying to understand one of the Linked List answers from `Cracking The Coding Interview` book. I've copied and pasted one of the answers from her GitHub and I get this error: `Question.java:5: error: package CtCILibrary does not exist
import CtCILibrary.LinkedListNode;` when I try to `import CtCILibrary.LinkedListNode;` in my `Question.java`. So at first, I thought it was just like including a Java library like so: `import java.util.Hashtable;`. But I got the error and realized that `import CtCILibrary.LinkedListNode` is not like `java.util.Hashtable`. So I decided to go online and I copied and pasted the code from http://ctci.googlecode.com/svn-history/r22/trunk/Java/CtCILibrary/CtCILibrary/LinkedListNode.java onto one of my text editors and named it `LinkedListNode.java`. And now, I get this error:

```
Question.java:7: error: cannot access LinkedListNode
    public static void deleteDupsA(LinkedListNode n) {
                                   ^
  bad source file: ./CtCILibrary.LinkedListNode.java
    file does not contain class LinkedListNode
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

And I'm stuck as to how to go from here. The problem is, `LinkedListNode.java` is in the same directory as my `Question.java`. And so I'm not sure what I need to do to be able to use the `LinkedListNode.java`. Any suggestions on how to fix this error:

Here is my `Question.java`:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import CtCILibrary.LinkedListNode;

public class Question {
    public static void deleteDupsA(LinkedListNode n) {
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        LinkedListNode previous = null;
        while (n != null) {
            if (set.contains(n.data)) {
                previous.next = n.next;
            } else {
                set.add(n.data);
                previous = n;
            }
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public static void deleteDupsC(LinkedListNode head) {
        if (head == null) return;
        LinkedListNode previous = head;
        LinkedListNode current = previous.next;
        while (current != null) {
            // Look backwards for dups, and remove any that you see.
            LinkedListNode runner = head;
            while (runner != current) { 
                if (runner.data == current.data) {
                    LinkedListNode tmp = current.next;
                    previous.next = tmp;
                    current = tmp;
                    /* We know we can't have more than one dup preceding
                     * our element since it would have been removed 
                     * earlier. */
                    break;
                }
                runner = runner.next;
            }

            /* If runner == current, then we didn't find any duplicate 
             * elements in the previous for loop.  We then need to 
             * increment current.  
             * If runner != current, then we must have hit the ‘break’ 
             * condition, in which case we found a dup and current has
             * already been incremented.*/
            if (runner == current) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void deleteDupsB(LinkedListNode head) {
        if (head == null) return;

        LinkedListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            /* Remove all future nodes that have the same value */
            LinkedListNode runner = current;
            while (runner.next != null) { 
                if (runner.next.data == current.data) {
                    runner.next = runner.next.next;
                } else {
                    runner = runner.next;
                }
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        LinkedListNode first = new LinkedListNode(0, null, null); //AssortedMethods.randomLinkedList(1000, 0, 2);
        LinkedListNode head = first;
        LinkedListNode second = first;
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            second = new LinkedListNode(i % 2, null, null);
            first.setNext(second);
            second.setPrevious(first);
            first = second;
        }
        System.out.println(head.printForward());
        LinkedListNode clone = head.clone();
        deleteDupsA(head);
        System.out.println(head.printForward());
        deleteDupsC(clone);
    }
}
```

And here is my `LinkedListNode.java`:

```
package CtCILibrary;

public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next;
    public LinkedListNode prev;
    public LinkedListNode last;
    public int data;
    public LinkedListNode(int d, LinkedListNode n, LinkedListNode p) {
        data = d;
        setNext(n);
        setPrevious(p);
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode n) {
        next = n;
        if (this == last) {
            last = n;
        }
        if (n != null && n.prev != this) {
            n.setPrevious(this);
        }
    }

    public void setPrevious(LinkedListNode p) {
        prev = p;
        if (p != null && p.next != this) {
            p.setNext(this);
        }
    }   

    public String printForward() {
        if (next != null) {
            return data + "->" + next.printForward();
        } else {
            return ((Integer) data).toString();
        }
    }

    public LinkedListNode clone() {
        LinkedListNode next2 = null;
        if (next != null) {
            next2 = next.clone();
        }
        LinkedListNode head2 = new LinkedListNode(data, next2, null);
        return head2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't have the LinkedListNode.java in the pakage CtCILibrary. Thats the problem. Create the folder CtCILibrary and place the file there. Or use eclipse, it will do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can include LinkedListNode class in the same java file and try accessing it, it will run. No need to keep it in a separate package and a separate file.